# how to pass radio button value from xml in selenium using testNG

Tags: java, xml, selenium, testng

i am using selenium with java and testNG, i want to pass value from xml file (parameterization).. i have passed all text values but need help to pass radio button value.

here is java code:

```
@Test(priority = 2)
@Parameters({"provider_name","clientId","Dpid","nsdl"})
public void addDematAccount(String provider_name,String clientId,String Dpid, String nsdl )
{
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href, '#/app/DematAccount/Add')]")).click();

    driver.findElement(By.id("ProviderName")).sendKeys(provider_name);
    driver.findElement(By.id("ClientId")).sendKeys(clientId);
    driver.findElement(By.id("DPId")).sendKeys(Dpid);


    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='Nsdl'][type='radio']")).click();
    driver.manage().timeouts().implicitlyWait(60, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    driver.findElement(By.name("btn")).click();
    driver.findElement(By.className("confirm")).click();
 }
```

here is XML file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE suite SYSTEM "http://testng.org/testng-1.0.dtd" >
<suite name="Sample Test Suite" verbose="1" >
  <test name="Test Demat account" >
    <parameter name="provider_name" value="testng"/>
    <parameter name="clientId" value="88544"/>
    <parameter name="Dpid" value="82843041"/>
    <parameter name="nsdl" value="nsdl"/>
  <classes>
     <class name="testngDemo.NewTestngDemo">
       <methods>
         <exclude name="deleteDematAccount" />
         <exclude name="logout" />
       </methods>
    </class>
  </classes>
 </test>
</suite>
```

HTML:

```
 <input class="ng-pristine ng-invalid ng-invalid-required ng-touched" name="NsdlCdsl" value="Nsdl" tabindex="4" required="" data-ng-model="model.NsdlCdsl" type="radio">

  <label for="rg-NSDL">
     &nbsp;NSDL
   </label>
```

Comment: How does this code fail?  Do you get a particular error?  It would also be helpful to look at the HTML of the page that these selectors are operating on.

Comment: there are 2 option for radio .. nsdl and cdsl. i want to select one of them which is passed in XML, there is no any error in this code but i want solution for what i really want.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you are facing issue how to fetch locator from passingg radio button value correct? as per provided code, you are passing string 'nsdl' but not used correctly in css selector. try by appending it..

```
   driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='"+nsdl+"'][type='radio']")).click();
```

let me know if this is not what you looking then please provide more information.

Thank You,
Murali

Comment: value = 'Nsdl' is for find the element.. i want to select or click on the radio button by passing value in XML

Comment: Hi, my bad i am still not got your point. you can pass <parameter name="my radio" value="my value"/> and can use this right? what is the issue here?

Answer (score 0):

I think I understand what you are asking for.  since the test is passed the arg "nsdl", you could do:

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("[value='" + nsdl + "'][type='radio']")).click();
```

Please note, though that the value in your xml is "nsdl" where as the value in the html is "Nsdl" (different case for the first letter).  you would need to update your XML